# What is the best approach for maintaining database? Fewer tables with lots of rows or lots of tables with fewer rows?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

What is the best approach for maintaining database? Fewer tables with hundreds of thousand (or millions) of rows or lots of tables with thousands of rows?
I am creating a website which will have a table which can reach hundreds of thousand (may be millions) of rows. However, I am thinking to divide it into 10-15 tables where each will have few thousands of rows. Is that the right way or should I follow the option of one table. Need to mention that data management won't be the issue for me in both cases. I am concerned with performance issue.
Also, is it good to have all the tables (that will be created in place of one big table) in same database or I can make 2-3 database with 4-5 tables in each database? Does access to more than one database on the same webpage affects the performance?

Comment: "Hundreds of thousands" is simply not that many rows for a modern SQL database.

Comment: @MattBall: Thanks for your reply. What if its in millions? Also, which approach is comparatively better?

Comment: The best approach is the right one for the needs of the project. There is no rule other than those imposed by the requirements and the limitations and capabilities of the technologies selected as suitable.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: What about creating 2-3 databases? I searched about it read that access to more than one database in the same webpage affects performance but not much written about this on internet.

Comment: Sorry buddy, but you need to learn the very basics first. All your questions makes not much sense. Database structure should be made out of relational logic, and nothing else. And your numerology has nothing to do with it. Create **one** table per logical matter (users, news, etc), put them all in **one** database and then start your long and toilsome way to your first hundred of rows. Trust me, your performance problems will come not from the number of tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that this question fits the format of this site very well.  As such, it might end up being closed.  But while it is open, I will answer it like this:

There is no rule about what is "best".

I would suggest some simple principles to follow.

1. **Beware of premature optimization** - Don't optimize until you can prove that it is a significant bottleneck.
2. **Use the database in a natural way** - Databases are pretty good at working out how to do things well if you use them in the way in which they were designed to work.  That is, use it to model your data in a way that fits the data being represented.
3. **Abstract the database from the interface** - If possible, try to code in such a way that the underlying database model can change if it has to in future, without you having to rewrite your entire program.
4. **Use the force** - Trust your instincts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored NoSql databases, such as Couchbase? These scale horizontally, without the need to do what you are proposing.

Comment: This is not the question where nosql have to be mentioned.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I cannot parse your grammar. Please elaborate.

Answer (score -2):

think about your future query's ...  how will you be using the tables ? .... what data do you want to retrieve ... and in what order/s ... are you going to want to search thru the tables...  I was always taught that the fastest way to sort data... was to store it pre-sorted ... if you can

Comment: I am thinking about all these issues that's why I want to make several tables instead of one. So as per your answer I should go with several tables option. What about creating 2-3 databases? I searched about it and read that access to more than one database in the same webpage affects performance but not much written about this on internet.